# Having trouble using result of mysql Min() in php

Tags: mysql

```
$minTime = "Select MIN(categoryTime) FROM List WHERE personStatus='Atendiendo' AND  depName='Admisiones'";

$Time = mysqli_query($con,$minTime);

     echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Main Record</th>
            <th>Tiempo Categoria</th>
            <th>Tiempo Estimando</th>
            <th>Time IN </th>
            </tr>";


while($min = mysqli_fetch_array($Time))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $min['categoryTime'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $min['categoryTime'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $min['categoryTime'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $min['categoryTime'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }

echo "</table>"; 
mysqli_close($con);
```

If I delete the `MIN()` function the query works perfectly...
The query work if I delete the `Min()` fuction. I tried `Least()` with no success.

Comment: The query as you have it will select one value (or none if the table is empty). What are you expecting?

Comment: You need to explain precisely what your problem is. 'not working' gives no clue as to what you want.

Comment: Bro I explain it really simple. `MIN()` dont work neither `least()` I test the query in the database SQL and work. But in my PHP file dont. When I remove the `Min()` from the PHP Query work and appear like 4 result. I only need the minimum of those 4.

Comment: 'min(0 doesn't work' - you already said that. Since it's fairly sure that `min()` _does_ work your problem is elsewhere. Repeating yourself doesn't help. Post examples of what happens and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: categoryTime in C:\xampp\htdocs\SLP-Validated1\ClockTest.php on line 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues here.

1. I think the snippet is missing:
   $Time =mysqli_query($con,$minTime);
   where $con is the connection.
2. When you add the MIN function around the categoryTime field, the label of the column in the resultset changes, so the reference to $min['categoryTime']  no longer returns anything. Try changing query to
   SELECT MIN(categoryTime) as minCat ...

then change the php array column reference to $min['minCat']

HTH

Comment: Did you try 2) in my amswer? You need to provide a name to the column with the AS in the SELECT clause, so that it can be easily referenced as a column in the array. Otherwise you'll need to change